# distribution of spaced normal variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

If we have samples $x_1$, $x_2$, ...,$x_M$ in $R^N$ obtained as follows:
1) $x_1$ is drawn from a normal distribution $N(0,\Sigma)$
2) $x_k$ ($k>1$) are also drawn from  $N(0,\Sigma)$, but only in the case that the distance between $x_k$ and any previous sample in $\{x_1, ..., x_{k-1}\}$ is larger than $d_0$, we will keep it.
3) We do 2) until we have $M$ samples.

In this case, is it possible to write pdf for $x_1$, $x_2$, ...,$x_M$. If not, is there some way to approximate it? Thanks.

Comment: Each $x_i$ is also a random vector? How you define "distance"?

Comment: just Euclidean distance.